# What is wrong with my use of indexOf?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find where the innerHTML of a div is in an array. I am making a 15 slider game (where it scrambles a 4x4 grid and you need to arrange it back). I am able to successfully get the tile number (the innerHTML) which is 1-15, but when I try and find the where it is in a global array (with non-repeating values 0-15, 0 representing the blank value), it only returns -1. Can you see what is wrong with how I am doing this?

```
var grid = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 ,15 ,0];

function move() {
    var tileNum = this.innerHTML;
    var ind = grid.indexOf(tileNum);
    var blankInd = grid.indexOf(0);
    console.log(tileNum);
    console.log(ind);
    console.log(blankInd);
}
```

Comment: You're passing String. Convert it to number.

Answer (score 2):

The `.innerHTML` property returns a string. You need to convert it to a number or it won't match the numeric array elements (`"1" !== 1`):

```
// using unary plus operator:
var tileNum = +this.innerHTML;
// OR:
var tileNum = Number(this.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inner HTML always returns a string value as result. You have to parse that to int before finding index.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script>
        var grid = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 ,15 ,0];

  function move() {
   var tileNum = "5";
   var ind = grid.indexOf(parseInt(tileNum));
   var blankInd = grid.indexOf(0);
   console.log(tileNum);
   console.log(ind);
   console.log(blankInd);
  }
        
        move();
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the string to number so it will work

```js
var grid = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14 ,15 ,0];

function move() {
 var tileNum = parseInt(this.innerHTML);
 var ind = grid.indexOf(tileNum);
 var blankInd = grid.indexOf(0);
 console.log(tileNum);
 console.log(ind);
 console.log(blankInd);
}
 move();
```